# React and styled-components - send props (emoji)

Tags: reactjs, styles, styled-components, emoji

Good day, could someone please tell me how I can pass the icon to the 'ButtonStyle' style.

I'll admit that I've tried many things and unfortunately no result. Is passing arguments correct? I will gladly accept any criticism.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const ButtonStyle = styled.button`
padding: 1em 1.5em;
margin: 1em;
background: white;
border: 0;
border-radius: 5px;
color ##ddd;
transition: background 0.4s;
transition-timing-function: ease;
cursor: pointer;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;


&:active {
  color: #000;
}
&:hover {
  background: #CC3333;
  color: #fff;
}

&:before {
  content: ':( NOOO ';
  content: ${props => props.icon || 'empty'};
}
`

const FontsButtonStyle = styled(ButtonStyle)`
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&display=swap');

font-weight: 800;
font-family: 'Bebas Neue', cursive;
`

const Button = ({type, disabled, name, title, onClick, className, icon}) => (
  <FontsButtonStyle icon={icon} type={type} disabled={disabled} name={name} onClick={onClick} className={className}>
    {title}
  </FontsButtonStyle>
);

Button.propTypes = {
  disabled:PropTypes.bool,
  type:PropTypes.string,
  name:PropTypes.string,
  title:PropTypes.string,
  onClick:PropTypes.func,
  className:PropTypes.string
};

Button.defaultProps = {
  disabled: false,
  type: 'button',
  name: 'Press me!',
  title: 'Press me!',
  onClick: (props) => {
    alert('onClick Works!')
  },
  className:'',
  icon: ''
};

export default Button;
```

`

I want to pass an icon to 'content'.
If no icon, empty field.

Icon inserted in defaultProps for testing.

Answer (score 0):

solution

```
const FontsButtonStyle = styled.button`
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&display=swap');

font-weight: 800;
font-family: 'Bebas Neue', cursive;

&:before {
  content: "${(props)=>props.icon}";
  }
`

const Button = ({type, disabled, name, title, onClick, className, icon}) => (
  <FontsButtonStyle icon={icon} type={type} disabled={disabled} name={icon} onClick={onClick} className={className}>
    {title}
  </FontsButtonStyle>
);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).